# How do I build my EF models so they are based on a stored procedure select

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am completely new to EF and a bit lost, to be honest.
I have an existing database, and everything is going through stored procedures. Even the selects are stored procedures. 
My model needs to use this, but I have no idea how to begin.
I assume I can really use the auto-generate, if the objects are to be based on the stored procedures output, instead of the tables.

I have tried googling, but to be honest, I don't think I know what to look for.

If I create an empty entity framework model, and build all the objects myself, can I somehow get the data by executing a stored procedure instead of mapping directly to a table?

And how do I do this? 
Any articles I need to read? My searching seems to always end up with fancy auto-generation articles, that seems to not apply in my case.

I know this is kind of a broad question, but I am somewhat lost here. Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit**

So, I have learnt that I can create a complex type, based on the stored select. But, I don't really see a way, to map update/insert/delete procedures onto this. I don't really understand how to link the entity type and the complex type together, if that is even possible or the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Function Imports to map the stored procedures - declaring their return type as a collection of your entities, and then use `ExecuteFunction`

eg:

```
context.ExecuteFunction<YourEntity>("YourSelectStoredProcedure")
```

Comment: I don't think I understand this. Would you still generate the model from the existing database tables, and then do this in the context.cs?

Comment: That depends - are the stored procedures simple selects, or do they add and omit columns - in which case you may need to define complex types.

Comment: I don't really get this. When I imported it all, it created complex types, for each imported stored procedure that selects. But does that mean, I should use the complex types (all suffixed _Result) instead of the entity types? Or do they link together somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
to start with create entity model (.dbmx file) from existing DB, which will include your existing stored procedure from your DB

after which u can go to entity model and check the Tab model browser, under stored procedures u can select the required SP, and also specify the type of data it will return 

check these links 

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/wriju/Using-Stored-Procedure-in-ADONET-Entity-Framework-40

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx
```